# Why can my first_pay not be defined? My second_pay works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal here is to calculate a salesperson's total pay for selling two vehicles, each one of any type. When they sell a new vehicle, they make $1,500. When they sell a used vehicle, they make a commission of 5% of the vehicle price. I have to make it prompt the salesperson to enter the type and selling price of each vehicle. Then, it should display the salesperson's total sales and total pay. I am not understanding what could be wrong with `first_pay`

```py
firstType = input('What is the first type of vehicle you are selling? ')
firstPrice = int(input('What is the price of the first vehicle? '))
secondType = input('What is second type of vehicle you are selling? ')
secondPrice = int(input('What is the price of the second vehicle? '))

if firstType == 'new':
    first_pay = 1500
elif firstType == 'used':
    first_pay = firstPrice * .05

if secondType == 'new':
    second_pay = 1500
elif secondType == 'used':
    second_pay = secondPrice * .05

    totalPay = first_pay + second_pay
    totalSales = firstPrice + secondPrice
    print('Total sales: $', format(totalSales, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print('Total pay: $', format(totalPay, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback when you run, and include the inputs required by you to cause the error. Your definition of `firstType` was "blocked" by your code fences. The first line containing the opening backticks must be empty or contain a language descriptor, like python in this case.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the program assumes the print statements are part of the else if statement. This works

```
firstType = input('What is second type of vehicle you are selling? ')
firstPrice = int(input('What is the price of the first vehicle? '))
secondType = input('What is second type of vehicle you are selling? ')
secondPrice = int(input('What is the price of the second vehicle? '))

if firstType == 'new':
    first_pay = 1500
elif firstType == 'used':
    first_pay = firstPrice * .05

if secondType == 'new':
    second_pay = 1500
elif secondType == 'used':
    second_pay = secondPrice * .05

totalPay = first_pay + second_pay
totalSales = firstPrice + secondPrice
print('Total sales: $', format(totalSales, ',.2f'), sep='')
print('Total pay: $', format(totalPay, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `firstType` is never defined so both paths of the if else block evaluate to false resulting in `first_pay` not being set.

Comment: The if statements wouldn't evaluate. Trying to lookup an undefined variable results in `NameError` and the program will crash. It's obviously a typo